# How can one solo-mine Monero using their laptop?

Tags: windows, solo-mining

How can I solo-mine with my laptop / desktop? Do I use the Monero cli software with Ubuntu or can I do it with the same software on Windows 10 too?

Comment: How would you solo mine outside of the wallet using command line ?
monero.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solo-mine with either the command line daemon or wallet (`monerod`/`monero-wallet-cli` with the `start_mining` command) or using the GUI ([instructions](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/solo_mine_GUI.html)). The same applies to whichever operating system you use.